# Определение раскладки

Tags: python

Недавно начал учить Python. В голову пришла идея сделать простую программу, которая будет менять символы с английской раскладки на русскую. Но у меня почему то не получается.

Помогите с решением задачи.

#### Вот мой код:

```
a = input()

for i in a:
    if i == "q":
        i = "й"
        continue
    elif i == "w":
        i = "ц"
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: `print(a.translate(str.maketrans('qwerty', 'йцукен')))`

Comment: Что именно не получается? Что не так с кодом из вопроса?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans' from 'string'

Answer (score 1):

Задача ясна и проблема тоже. Дело в том что, вы пытаетесь менять саму строку, а этого делать нельзя, и поэтому у вас ничего не получается сделать. Для этого можно использовать переменные

```
text = input()
translated_text = ''

for letter in text:
    tranlated = ''
    if letter == "q":
        translated = "й"
        continue
    elif letter == "w":
        translated = "ц"
        continue
    elif letter == 'a':
        translated = 'ф'
        continue
    ## итд.
    translated_text += translated

print(translated_text)
```

Но еще можно написать так чтобы, не прописывать `if/else`:

```
en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,."
rus = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю"
text = input()
translated_text = ''
for l in text:
    try:
        translated_index = en.index(l)
        translated_word = rus[translated_index]
    except:
        translated_word = l

    translated_text += translated_word

print(translated_text)
```

Также с использованием встроенной функции `maketrans`

```
en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,."
rus = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю"
text = input()

translated_text = text.translate(str.maketrans(en, rus))
print(translated_text)
```